# How to review suggested edits that remove a single tag from a bunch of questions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Today, I reviewed the following suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3074520

The editor removed the `xcode` tag in this edit. I approved the edit. But on the next reviews, the same user also removed the `xcode` tag on different questions.

Can I approve the review? Because if I approve it, the user will think to remove the tag for all question for edit...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retagging improperly tagged questions is *generally* an acceptable use of edits. However, we want to make sure that users are improving posts when they retag.

If a few edits are simply retags, it's passable (though it's still *very* much appreciated if you improve the post). However, if the user is editing a slew of posts, they should really be improving the post.

If you see a user retagging more than just a few posts, I highly recommended improving the post yourself, and marking the edit as unhelpful when you submit. You may also simply reject the edit as too minor, or give a custom reason.